# Parallel gnu-make skips commands

Tags: gnu-make

Given an empty file a.c and the following Makefile -

```
CC=gcc
l.a : l.a(a.o)
    ranlib l.a
    echo done

l.a(a.o) : a.c

clean::
    rm -f l.a a.o
```

Running the command "make clean ; make" gives the following output -

```
rm -f l.a a.o
gcc    -c -o a.o a.c
ar rv l.a a.o
a - a.o
ranlib l.a
echo done
done
```

Running the command "make clean ; make -j2" gives the following output -

```
rm -f l.a a.o
gcc    -c -o a.o a.c
ar rv l.a a.o
a - a.o
```

Why does "make -j2" skip the commands listed under the first rule?

This occurs consistently on a 32-bit single processor system with gnu make 3.79.1
Does not occur on a 64-bit multi-core system with gnu make 3.81.
This is a very shortened example of a larger Makefile where I ran into the problem.

So, I made the example Makefile a bit more "complex" as follows -

```
AR := flock make.lock ar
RANLIB := flock make.lock ranlib

CC=gcc
l.a : l.a(a.o) l.a(b.o)
        echo doing ranlib
        $(RANLIB) l.a
        echo done

l.a(a.o) : a.c

l.a(b.o) : b.c

clean::
        rm -f l.a a.o b.o
```

The flock() trick is my invention (perhaps a re-invention) to serialize "ar".
Output -

```
> make clean ; make -j1
rm -f l.a a.o b.o
gcc    -c -o a.o a.c
flock make.lock ar rv l.a a.o
ar: creating l.a
a - a.o
gcc    -c -o b.o b.c
flock make.lock ar rv l.a b.o
a - b.o
echo doing ranlib
doing ranlib
flock make.lock ranlib l.a
echo done
done
rm a.o b.o

> make clean ; make -j2
rm -f l.a a.o b.o
gcc    -c -o a.o a.c
gcc    -c -o b.o b.c
flock make.lock ar rv l.a a.o
flock make.lock ar rv l.a b.o
ar: creating l.a
a - a.o
a - b.o
rm a.o b.o
```

Comment: Do you get consistent output from this with `-j2`? In some quick tests I get varied output depending on how quickly I run the commands. I tested with both make 3.81 and make 4.0. This seems to be some sort of race but I don't see it yet.

Comment: My [test](https://gist.github.com/deryni/1c9055860b18083fac92).

Comment: Posted additional info and example in main writeup. @EtanReisner